# Outlook OAuth2 can't redirect to application

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, outlook

I'm currently trying use the outlook mail service to obtain contacts/appointments and mails. However I've stumbled upon a problem.

I'm using [OAuth2Swift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift) as library to make all my OAuth calls since I'm integrating multiple services.

I created a `URL scheme`like described in their `README`
[image]

Then I created a `Constants` file which looks like this

```
struct Consumer {
    let consumerKey: String
    let consumerSecret: String
    let authorizeURL: String
    let accessTokenURL: String
    let responseType: String?
    let requestTokenURL: String?
}

let Outlook = Consumer(
    consumerKey: "",
    consumerSecret: "",
    authorizeURL: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    accessTokenURL: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    responseType: "code",
    requestTokenURL: nil)
```

I created an application for outlook on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com
generated my key and secret and filled them in inside my application.

I added the `mobile application` platform to my app. Which tells me to use the redirect URI `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`

So my code to authorise looks like this

```
@IBAction func btn_Outlook(_ sender: Any) {
        let oauthOU = OAuth2Swift(
            consumerKey: Outlook.consumerKey,
            consumerSecret: Outlook.consumerSecret,
            authorizeUrl: Outlook.authorizeURL,
            accessTokenUrl: Outlook.accessTokenURL,
            responseType: Outlook.responseType!)
        
        oauthOU.authorizeURLHandler = SafariURLHandler(viewController: self, oauthSwift: oauthOU)
        oauthOU.authorize(
            withCallbackURL: "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
            scope: "https://outlook.office.com/Mail.ReadWrite https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Send https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.ReadWrite https://outlook.office.com/Contacts.ReadWrite https://outlook.office.com/Tasks.ReadWrite",
            state: state,
            success: { credential, response, parameters in
                print("logged in with \(credential), with response \(response) and parameters \(parameters)")},
            failure: { error in
                print("error occured \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            )
        }
```

when I run the code I first get a screen to enter my mail/password. When I enter my mail it will redirect me to a different page/portal where I can enter my password. When I've entered my password it will show me the permissions screen.

[image]

as soon as I hit `yes` it will give me an error saying "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid." I'm pretty sure this has to do with the `redirect URI` but I'm not sure what to do to actually fix this.

I'm hoping someone is able to help me out with this!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to specify the identifier `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` in your URL scheme settings (see first image: there is no identifier set)

Comment: I added it but it didn't make any difference the same message shows up

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to handle `redirect URI` in AppDelegate from OAuthSwift library! You've to handle the callback in AppDelegate as below.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
  if (url.host == "oauth-callback") {
    OAuthSwift.handle(url: url)
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: forgot to add that but I have that method in my delegate and it doesn't even get called when trying to sign in with outlook. it does get called when I do it with twitter for instance

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? I have exactly the same problem trying to authenticate with OneDrive from a Xamarin-Mac-app.